# How to implement GoogleOR-Tool in Laravel? especially for the "Assignment as a Min Cost Flow Algorithm" (Java)

Tags: laravel, or-tools

Im gonna implement the algoritm of Google OR Tools for job matching but doesnt know how to combine laravel with it.

i'm just start the laravel project now and the core is the algorithm. I already had the algorithm but doesnt know how to put in to project

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the c++ libraries in PHP, most likely using swig. 
Then use the build libraries.

Tough journey ahead if you have no experience with SWIG.

Alternative route, create a server accepting json/protobuf input, and connect the PHP code with it.